# Prove: If $x$ is a base point for a topological space $X$, then $U(x)\in B$ for every base $B$ of $X$

Tags: general-topology, discrete-mathematics

Prove: If point $x$ for a topological space $X$ has a minimal neighbourhood $U(x)$, then $U(x)\in B$ for **every** base $B$ of $X$.

Comment: Write $U(x)$ as a union of base elements. Then use the fact that $U(x)$ is minimal.

Comment: Welcome to Math.SE! Note that when posting a question, you should at least show some of your efforts. What have you tried?

Comment: I want to link with 2 ways: 1) Let V∈B where x∈V∈U(x), but by the definition U(x): V=U(x) 
2) β is a base iff for every x in X and U(x) as a neighborhood, there exists a B∈β: x∈B∈U(x)

Answer (score 1):

Let $\mathcal{B}$ be *any* base for $X$. As $U(x)$ is open and contains $x$, for some $B\in \mathcal{B}$ be have $x \in B \subseteq U(x)$, by the definition of a base for $X$. The inclusion cannot be proper as that would contradict the minimality of $U(x)$. So $B = U(x)$ and so $U(x) \in \mathcal{B}$.